# Compute Module 4 and Camera Module v2.1 - How to configure?

Tags: camera, compute-module

I am confused by the instructions posted [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/computemodule/cmio-camera.md) which explain how to configure various Compute Module devices with camera modules.

These instructions appear to be confusing as they describe at least 3 different ways to obtain the required file `/boot/dt-blob.bin`. (Two downloads with wget and the multiple different configuration options which can be compiled to produce a `.bin` file from a `.dts` file.

If anyone has any experience of getting a single camera module working with a CM4 and IO board please could you give me some brief instructions on what I need to do. I am somewhat at loss here.

I understand that the binary blob is to configure the Pi GPIO hardware when the GPU initializes, but this is about the limit of my understanding.

Also if there are any mods about could you please tag this with `compute-module-4` and remove the tag `compute-module`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Compute Module IO Board + Compute Module 4 Instructions:

- Connect Camera Module to Compute Module IO board using **Raspberry Pi Zero Camera Cable**
- Single Camera: `sudo wget https://datasheets.raspberrypi.org/cmio/dt-blob-cam1.bin -O /boot/dt-blob.bin`

OR

- Dual Camera: `sudo wget https://datasheets.raspberrypi.org/cmio/dt-blob-dualcam.bin -O /boot/dt-blob.bin`
- Camera should be connected to Camera 1 port
- Reboot

Should just work. None of the "Advanced" instructions (from [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/computemodule/cmio-camera.md)) are required.

My primary issue was not knowing which of the two camera ports I should connect the camera to, but I was also confused by the "Advanced" section which isn't needed for basic operation or to just get something working.

Answer (score 0):

For dual cameras, two jumpers are also needed on J6 if using the IO-Board.